# script Multiple Commands

Tags: bash, scripting, terminal, cron, output

I have a PHP script I'm running from Cron. I want to save its output to file, but also want to save the shell output to a different file. Ideally, I'd like to have this in one line. As such, I tried the following:

```
script "/folder/log/file.errors."`date +"%Y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S"`".txt" && /usr/bin/php /folder/file.php > "/folder/log/file.php."`date +"%Y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S"`".txt"
```

But it only runs the first command (before `&&`). Likewise, if I use `;` instead of `&&`.

When I run this as two separate commands, it works just fine:

```
root:~# script "/folder/log/file.errors."`date +"%Y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S"`".txt"
root:~# /usr/bin/php /folder/file.php > "/folder/log/file.php."`date +"%Y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S"`".txt"
```

How can I join these two commands into one command/line?

Also, when run via Cron, will it be necessary for me to run an `exit` command after the above code in order for [script](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/script.1.html) to properly save to file?

Comment: May I know the purpose of using script command with a txt file?

Comment: @Vikyboss, it doesn't have to be a txt file. It can be any type of file. I just want to save the output to any file for debugging purposes (instead of going through PHP's actual error log).

Comment: The reason the part after && not working is because the first script is not exiting with successful exit code, i.e. zero. if you replace && with semicolon, it should work, unless there is typo error, provided, they run fine on separate lines.

Comment: By script you talking about the unix 'script' command?

Comment: @Vikyboss, yes the [script](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/script.1.html) command.

Comment: @MelBurslan, I just tried it again with a semicolon, but terminal only displays `Script started, file is /folder/log/file.errors.2016-01-29.15-18-38.txt` (and creates this file) and the part after the semicolon does not run.

Comment: @Pamela, Sorry overlooked your post. But may I know the purpose of using script command here? May be that could help more.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you were trying to run the unix `script` command, as it changes the things. Consider this, with the script command, you are creating a new shell (with logging capability) while the second part of your command is still waiting for the first part to exit so that it can proceed. Because your first  (parent) shell is going to run it

Comment: @roaima: But Pamela says she is getting `file.errors.2016-01-29.15-18-38.txt`, so it's not choking on the `%`s.

Comment: My suggestion: instead of relying on `script` logging, especially if this will eventually be a cron job, consider sending output and error messages to one or more designated files(s) in your php code. When you run it in cron, it will create a session log unless you divert it to something like `>/dev/null 2>&1` directive. So, as a debug tool you can check that cron log

Comment: @MelBurslan, I forgot about cron logging (as I'm testing the script via terminal before making a cron job)! Yes, that will work perfectly here. I'm not sure if you want to say that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: As long as you found your answer, getting an uptick in the points system, is not that important to me. Good luck with your cron job.

Comment: @MelBurslan that is quite noble of you but it would be great if you could just whip up a quick answer regardless. Otherwise, the question won't be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per terdon's request, I am posting this comment as an answer, so that the question can be marked as "answered"

> Instead of relying on `script` logging, especially if this will
>   eventually be a cron job, consider sending output and error messages
>   to one or more designated files(s) in your php code. When you run it
>   in cron, it will create a session log unless you divert it to
>   something like `>/dev/null 2>&1` directive. So, as a debug tool you can
>   check that cron log